# easy cms/framework for making a twitter site

Tags: twitter, frameworks, content-management-system

I was reading a thread last year about cms softwares that are used for making social sites... and basically someone said it takes less time to do something with a certain cms and the response was you could make a whole twitter in seconds using so-and-so framework, that doesn't mean its best overall. I surly bookmarked that so-and-so website and were planing to test it. but its not anywhere in my bookmarks and searching in google didn't help. does anyone know what that cms/framework for creating twitter-like websites? 
Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you're looking for, but take a look at http://openmicroblogger.org/.

You can take a look at other possibilities, as told in here: http://socialcmsbuzz.com/ever-wanted-to-start-your-own-twitter-clone-now-you-can-02122008/.

Hope this helps,